# CSS moving text by scale Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a problem with some css code.

I build a hover with a image inside that scales. In every browser it seems okey except Safari.

I used this code to fix the problem, **did not work.**

```
transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

The complete code you can find here.
**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ylambers/bbfLxy2x/2/)**

I think it is some kind of antialiased problem, but i have no idea how to fix it :(

Comment: I am running Safari 5 (old) on Windows, and it looks basically the same as in Firefox (latest). In both cases, the large "Lorem Ipsum" text is replaced by longer string in smaller font size and the background "zooms in". Can you clarify what is different in your version of Safari?

Comment: Did you try using -webkit-transform?

Comment: I am using version 8.0.6 and when the hover is finished, the text moves a little bit.

Comment: @Sean_Murrin, he uses `-webkit-transform` in his jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[SOLVED]*

I just fixed the problem thnx to bwright.

I added

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`
to the **wrap img**

and 
`transform: perspective(1px) scale(1.2) ;`
To the **wrap:hover img**

It fixed the problem and now its smooth in safari.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `perspective` of `1px` to your scale transforms, i.e.:

```
transform: perspective(1px) scale(1.2);
```

This can fix common cross-browser problems similar to what you are describing. See also: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/

Comment: I read the article and tried the solluction, but without succes.